# Apply log2 transformation to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to apply log2 with `applymap` and `np2.log2`to a data and show it using boxplot, here is the code I have written:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

################################
    # a.
df.boxplot()
plt.title('Raw Data')

################################
    # b.
df.applymap(np.log2)
df.boxplot()
plt.title('Normalized Data')
```

and below is the boxplot I get for my RAW data which is okay, but I do get the same boxplot after applying log2 transformation !!! can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and what should be corrected to get the normalized data with applymap and np.log2
[image]

Comment: try `df = df.applymap(yourfunc)`[API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap)

Comment: you're not modifying anything with `df.applymap(np.log2)`, the returned result is not subsequently used. Do `df2 = df.applymap(np.log2)` and use the new df for plotting.

Comment: wow great @ShiheZhang I wasted so much time on this very tiny point, thank you !

Comment: @HaleemurAli thank you, I got it know :)

Comment: @ShiheZhang since you commented first, you can post your comment as answer, and I will accept it :)

Comment: @Hazmat Glad to be helpful.

Comment: @Hazmat Before accepting an answer, you better stop and reconsider whether `applymap` is the right function to use here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ with `applymap ` you can change the `func` easier.

Comment: @ShiheZhang Maybe... but that's outside the scope of this question ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [API Reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap) `DataFrame.applymap(func)`

> Apply a function to a DataFrame that is intended to operate
>   elementwise, i.e. like doing map(func, series) for each series in the
>   DataFrame

It won't change the `DataFrame` you need to get the return value and use it.

Comment: While what you are suggesting is not _wrong_, it's horribly inefficient when numpy is equally good at working with the entire dataframe at once. I've added some timings to my answer so you can see what's going on. `applymap` is no better than a nested loop.

Comment: That could be another question "What's the efficient way to do log2 with every element in dataframe".And you would be right.

Answer (score 15):

A *much* faster way to do this would be:

```
df = np.log2(df)
```

Don't forget to assign the result back to `df`.

Comment: Thank you coldspeed, I will keep your +ve adivce, however I have an homework and that requires me to use applymap & np.log2, so I will take  @Shihe Zhang's answer as approved answer

Comment: @Hazmat I understand homework is your highest priority but look at the bigger picture here. Anyway, you can up vote all answers, even if you can only accept one.

Comment: Okay, that sounds legitimate to me, and in the long run, I would definitely just use (`df = np.log2(df)`) the answer you provided! so I +1'oned your answer as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas now has the [transform()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function, which in your case amounts to:

```
df = df.transform(lambda x: np.log2(x))
```